# Excel: Index/match to return array

Tags: arrays, excel, match, lookup, countif

**Sheet1 & Sheet 2**
[image: sheet 1]   [image: sheet 2]

I am looking for a way that can perform the following task in excel for each of the column A values:

- Match value `A2` of sheet 1 to the right value in array `A2:C2` from Sheet2 and return the respective array beneath the matching column (in this case `A3:A4` from Sheet2).
- This array would then need to be used for a `COUNTIF` function for finding value `B2` within this returning array.

**Sheet1 (Results)**
[image: sheet 1-results]

Comment: Worksheets don't use arrays, perhaps the term you mean is "range"? (Unless you're implying that this should be done via VBA?)  Either way, your explanation is a little tough to follow but I suspect you're adding unneeded extra steps and over-complicating a simple task.

Comment: In short I need is to match 1 cell to a 1-row array, and return the column values beneath that matching cell

Comment: as I mentioned there are no arrays in Excel worksheets. Perhaps it would be helpful if you include representative examples (As opposed to A's and 1's and 0's), and explain what you're starting with, and what you need to end with (without your theory of steps in between like array's or index/match) .  Also, as it is I don't know if the "results" image is the "final" output that you need or a transition step, like before/after "the column values beneath that matching cell".

Comment: "For next time" (assuming the answer below works for you) it's much better if your example source data is in a form that can be copied (instead of an image), so others can test their theory in trying to match your desired output. One way would be to use [this site](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) with the "compact" setting.)

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was a bit terrible. Thanks for your response. I think I got it now

Comment: Thanks - will use it next time. As you imagined, this was my first post..:)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. No  worries.  I've sen thousands of first post, many FAR less clear than this!  It's all good as long as people are willing to take advice for next time. :-)   (Welcome, by the way!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in sheet1!c2 and fill down,

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet2!A:C, 0, MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$2:$2, 0)), B2)
```

Comment: "...or, maybe Jeeped will come along and effortlessly find clarity in the mud."   (Must be a 4x4'er)

Comment: @Jeeped I should have guessed.  I've spent plenty of time on that site.  ...and plenty more on the muddy V.I. trails.

Comment: @Jeeped - it took me a sec to realize what you meant but now I picture it on on your vehicle - I now assume your 4x4 is labelled with the nickname.  Ashlee was my dog's name and stuck for different reasons, but it's interesting to see how I'm treated differently by people assuming I'm female: sometimes better, sometimes worse, sometimes they will not leave me alone.  I was even proposed to, on Valentine's Day, on an MS Access forum, by a man in India.